# El index no enlaza los ficheros .css. Error MIME type text/html

Tags: javascript, html, css

después de terminar mi web en local, la he subido al servidor, y tengo el siguiente error con los archivos .css y .js :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado una solución y no hay manera. Creo que es debido a un problema con las rutas. Si a alguien le ha pasado algo similar y quiere compartir una solución se lo agradecería.
Añado captura de como enlazo los ficheros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado también la estructura de mi proyecto por si puede servir de ayuda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Usas alguna tecnología en particular?

Comment: Estoy usando PHP siguiendo MVC, y en el cliente, uso javascript, jquery, bootstrap.

Comment: Puedes poner como enlazas los archivos? Has probado a poner el / para que el enlace vaya desde el root?? Por stylesheet se refiere al archivo css

Comment: Si como no, he editado el post con la captura del enlace a los ficheros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finalmente he conseguido arreglar el error y saber de que se trataba. Lo quiero compartir aquí para agradecer a quien ha intentado ayudarme y para que alguien que tenga el mismo problema pueda solucionarlo. El problema era el siguiente:
- No enlazaba bien las rutas desde mi .html a los archivos .css, img y demás porque en el servidor donde está alojada mi web usa una distro de Linux, por lo que distingue en Mayúsculas y minúsculas, entonces yo tenía carpetas que empezaban con Mayus como Resources y en la ruta lo escribía como resources.

Este era el fallo, una idiotez, pero espero que le sirva para alguien más adelante.

Answer (score 0):

a veces me ha sucedido lo mismo, y lo único que he cambiado ha sido lo siguiente:

- Utilizar solo type="text/css" (quitar el rel="stylesheet").
- Colocar un / delante de la ruta para que coja como referencia la raíz del proyecto.

¿Estás utilizando algún framework?

Espero sea de ayuda mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias. Lo acabo de probar y sigue con coger los estilos del css. Lo que si ha sucedido es que al quitar el rel="stylesheet" como dices, ya no me da el Warning, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Por cierto, no estoy usando ningún framework, simplemente es PHP siguiendo el patrón MVC sin framework. Funciona todo, solo que al subir todos los archivos al servidor, me ha ocurrido esto.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `href="./resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: Tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Este error se debe a que no le estamos indicando al navegador el tipo de contenido tiene que renderizar y lo procesa como si fuese texto plano, para solucionarlo solo basta añadir el siguiente meta en el header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
```

Dejo la referencia donde se da mas detalle: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Server-side/Configuring_server_MIME_types